# Why maven aggregator project looks for jar file to install?

Tags: maven, jar, installation, pom.xml

I have an aggregator POM (`<packaging>pom`) with a few modules. The modules build fine but the aggregator itself has a strange error. When I do `mvn clean install` on the aggregator it normally calls `default-install` and installs the `pom.xml` in the local repository. But then right after that it calls the `additional-install` and looks for a JAR file in the project `target` directory to install to the local repository but it does not find a JAR file and fails.

Why does Maven try to install a JAR file from an aggregator project where an aggregator project never builds a JAR file so why is it trying to find one to install?

There is no error other than this and `mvn clean package` builds fine because it doesn’t involve installing.

The project is complex so I didn’t paste any code. If anyone could give me a clue as to why an aggregator POM with `<packaging>pom` would try to install a JAR I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Can you make an similar example and put that on Github and add a logging output ...cause at the moment I don't understand what your problem really is?

Comment: That may be caused by bogus plugin configuration, but cannot say more without seeing your actual project config... We'll need your `pom.xml` content to help, at least the content of the `<build>` element. If there is too much content you can create an example Github project or use a service like Pastebin

Comment: Is there an `<execution>` with `<id>additional-install` declared for `maven-install-plugin` in your POM explicitely? Please supply the relevant parts of your POM, at least and the error msg.